# Label/Value near each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to show the label and value horizontally together, like:

```
Team: Lorem Ipsum and then some
```

Currently they are on top of each other.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="control-label">Team:</label>
      <p class="form-control-static">Lorem Ipsum and then some</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes down because you are adding the < p > tag which automatically line-breaks since it is a paragraph tag... Use span class instead...

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label">Team:</label>
            <span class="form-control-static">Lorem Ipsum and then some</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if you really want to use the < p > tag, can I suggest some style tag preferably with an id:

```
p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```